# Null Object When Passed Into An Anonymous Inner Class

Tags: java, inner-classes, java1.4

When passing a final object (A String in the code below) it shows up as null when printed from the anonymous inner class.  However, when a final value type or straight final String is passed in, its value is correctly displayed.  What does `final` really mean in context of the anonymous inner class and why is the object passed null?

```
public class WeirdInners
{
    public class InnerThing
    {
        public InnerThing()
        {
            print();
        }

        public void print(){

        }
    }

    public WeirdInners()
    {
        final String aString = "argh!".toString();
        final String bString = "argh!";
        System.out.println(aString);
        System.out.println(bString);


        InnerThing inner =new InnerThing(){
            public void print()
            {
                System.out.println("inner"+aString); // When called from constructor, this value is null.
                System.out.println("inner"+bString); // This value is correctly printed.
            }
        };

        inner.print();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        WeirdInners test1 = new WeirdInners();
    }

}
```

This is very strange behavior to me because the expectation is that the String *is* an object, why does calling `toString()` change things?

Other info:  this behavior is only observed using Java 1.4, not in Java 5.  Any suggestions on a workaround?  Not calling `toString()` on an existing String is fair enough, but since this is only an example, it has real world implications if I perform it on a non-String object.

Comment: What results are you seeing under Java 1.4?  I'm using Java 6, and I get (something that probably won't format nicely and there's no preview for comments):

argh!
argh!
innerargh!
innerargh!
innerargh!
innerargh!

Not that it helps you any, but the EOL Notification for Java 1.4 was announced in December, 2006, and the EOSL for Java 1.4 was a year ago this Friday.  Java 5's EOL Notification was in April, 2008, and it hits its EOSL this Friday.  Any chance you can upgrade to Java 6?  http://java.sun.com/products/archive/eol.policy.html

Comment: You are seeing the expected output. The 1.4 behavior is innernull when using "argh!".toString();.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check the section on `compile-time constants` in the JLS, you'll see that calling `.toString()` does make a difference. As does nonsense like prefixing with `false?null+"":`.

What is important here is the relative ordering of setting the fields that are closed over and the constructor. If you use `-target 1.4` or later (which is not the default in 1.4!) then the fields will be copied before calling the super. With the spec before 1.3 this was illegal bytecode.

As is often the case in these cases, `javap -c` is useful to see what the javac compiler is doing. The spec is useful for understanding why (should you have sufficient patience).

Answer (score 1):

It is dangerous to invoke overridden methods from a superclass constructor, as they will be called before the subclass-part of the object is initialized.

Moreover, an inner class accessing final variables of an enclosing scope will actually access copies of those variables (that's why they need to be final), and these copied fields reside in the anonymous subclass.

I suspect the reason `bString` is treated differently is that its value is known at compile time, which allows the compiler to inline the field access in the subclass, making the time that field is initialized irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you trigger undefined behaviour when the constructor of InnerThing() passes (implicitly) its `this` to the print method of an anonymous subclass of InnerThing while the object is not fully constructed. This `this` in turn relies on an implicit reference to the `this` of WierdInners.

Calling `.toString()` moves initialisation of aString from compile time to runtime. Why the undefined behaviour differs between Java 1.4 and 1.5 is a JVM implementation detail probably.